# $window.open with context / headers

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, window.open

I need to open a window in order to download a file from api endpoint.

currently I am doing this:

```
let url = this.apiBaseUrl + "/exportToExcel/" + id;
this.$window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Problem is:
the request looses the context (security in header) so that my API Controller blocks the request.
How can I get around this issue?

Comment: Only request headers you can set are when using ajax. Could do ajax download instead. Easy to search how

Comment: There is an open issue for adding support for headers to the window.open function in the HTML standard. Please voice your opinions and needs on there. [https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/7810)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file first, then open it:

```
var url = this.apiBaseUrl + "/exportToExcel/" + id;
var headers = {
   //Put headers here
};
var config = { 
   responseType: 'blob',
   headers: headers
};
$http.get(url, config).then(function (response) {
    var blob = response.data;
    var u = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(u,"_blank");
});
```

This will GET the file as a [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), convert it to a [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), then open it in a new window.

Comment: thanks this works but the file is not beeing stored with the filename I set in response header but like '331a5ddf-2d06-443f-816d-f970c4ab52e5'

Comment: okay just figured it out. instead of using window.open I am using saveAs now:         let file = new Blob([data], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
                    saveAs(file, "abc.xls");